# Array intersect Hive

Tags: arrays, apache, hive, intersect

I have two arrays of string in Hive like

```
{'value1','value2','value3'}
{'value1', 'value2'}
```

I want to merge arrays without duplicates, result:

```
{'value1','value2','value3'}
```

How I can do it in hive?

Comment: why is this tagged with java?

Comment: this is not intersection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a UDF for this. Klout has a bunch of opensource HivUDFS under the package 
brickhouse. Here is the [github link](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse). They have a bunch of UDF's that exactly serves your purpose. 
Download,build and add the JAR. Here is an example

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION combine AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUDF';
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION combine_unique AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUniqueUDAF';

select combine_unique(combine(array('a','b','c'), array('b','c','d'))) from reqtable;

OK
["d","b","c","a"]
```

Comment: There is also 'intersect_array', which give the actual elements in common ( 'b','c')


Sayan, Thanks so much for spreading the word about Brickhouse !!!
 I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic package. It has some really great functions. I tried with combine_unique. It was not accepting 2 arrays. Hence this solution. The wiki needs to be modified

Answer (score 6):

A native solution could be that:

```
SELECT id, collect_set(item)
FROM table
LATERAL VIEW explode(list) lTable AS item
GROUP BY id;
```

Firstly explode with lateralview, and next group by and remove duplicates with collect_set.