# Hive : Join to array of string columns

Tags: arrays, hive

I have a HIVE Table with following schema like this:

```
hive>desc books;
gen_id                  int                                         
author                  array<string>                               
rating                  double                               
genres                  array<string>  

hive>select * from books;

| gen_id         | rating    | author          |genres
+----------------+-------------+---------------+----------
| 1              | 10        | ["A","B"]       | ["X","Y"]  
| 2              | 20        | ["C","A"]       | ["Z","X"]
| 3              | 30        | ["D"]           | ["X"]
```

Is there a query where I can perform some SELECT operation and that returns individual rows, like this:

```
| gen_id      |  rating        | JoinData
+-------------+---------------+-------------
| 1           | 10            | ["A","B","X","Y"]
| 2           | 20            | ["C","A","Z","X"]
| 3           | 30            | ["D","X"]
| 1           | 10            | "Y"
```

Can someone guide me how can get to this result. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is in this post: 
  
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578477/array-intersect-hive

For the people, that don't want to enter the thread:

1) Create a temp function using UDF
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION combine AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUDF';

2) make a select statement

```
select gen_id
    , rating
    , combine(author, genres) as JoinData 
from books
```