# How to compute the intersections and unions of two arrays in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

For example, the intersection

```
select intersect(array("A","B"), array("B","C"))
```

should return

```
["B"]
```

and the union

```
 select union(array("A","B"), array("B","C"))
```

should return

```
["A","B","C"]
```

What's the best way to make this in Hive? I have checked the hive documentation, but cannot find any relevant information to do this.

Comment: Did you try  `select array("A","B") UNION ALL select array("B","C"))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array intersect Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578477/array-intersect-hive)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem solution is here. Go to the [githubLink](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/tree/8fce0ac98aef422772ac89de7a620caac47ccc9d/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect), there is lot of udfs are created by **klout**. Download, crate the JAR and add the JAR in the hive. Example

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION combine AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUDF';
 CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION combine_unique AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUniqueUDAF';

select combine_unique(combine(array('a','b','c'), array('b','c','d'))) from reqtable;

OK
["d","b","c","a"]
```

Comment: The correct function found in the link above should be [brickhouse.udf.collect.ArrayIntersectUDF](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/ArrayIntersectUDF.java) which can be used as `intersect_array(array1, array2, ...)` and [brickhouse.udf.collect.ArrayUnionUDF](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/ArrayUnionUDF.java) as `array_union(array1, array2, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```c
array_intersect(array1,array2,...)
```

and

```c
array_union(array1, array2, ...)
```