# How to get the intersect of two array fields in Hive?

Tags: arrays, hive

There are two arrays in my table, say, `array1` and `array2`.
One row , for example, `array1 = [1,2,3,4]` and `array2 = [2,4,9]`

I want to get the elements that both `array1` and `array2` have, that is `[2,4]`.
How can I realize it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145842/how-to-compute-the-intersections-and-unions-of-two-arrays-in-hive    --use UDF from github as answered in this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compute the intersections and unions of two arrays in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145842/how-to-compute-the-intersections-and-unions-of-two-arrays-in-hive)